# What do you call these ways of representing pronunciation?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

> 1. Honest **/änəst/**
> 2. Honest **[ahh-nest]**

What are these called?

Comment: Are you asking which encoding scheme is used for each of those? Both are non-standard, but it different ways.

Comment: An alphabet specifically chosen for this purpose is a "phonetic alphabet."

Answer (score 1):

A ***phonetic representation*** of a word is a representation of its pronunciation.

Wikipedia defines [*phonetic representation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_representation) as follows:

> the representation of speech sounds using symbols in phonetic alphabet

Similarly, it defines [*phonetic transcription*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_transcription) as follows:

> the visual representation of speech sounds (or phones). The most common type of phonetic transcription uses a phonetic alphabet

There are many different ways to represent a word phonetically. Both of your examples are phonetic representations.

Answer (score 0):

Fake pronunciations?

Both are in made-up random notations that run utterly contrary to the standard notation recognized worldwide.

That should instead be /ˈɒnɪst/, /ˈɑnɪst/, /ˈɒnəst/, or /ˈɑnəst/ in IPA (International Phonetic Notation).

Comment: Anything other than IPA is not necessarily "fake."